# What is a computers default gateway?

Tags: default, gateway

After entering `ip route` the following information came up:

```
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 metric 100.
```

Is this the default gateway? If not what is?

Comment: Do you want the definition of "default gateway", or the line in the output which shows the default gateway? If the latter, please add output to the question..

Comment: To get just the IP: `ip route | awk '/default/ {print $3; exit}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *default gateway* is the host designated as the default router; that is, when your computer wants to connect to another computer which is not on the local network, it will send the data packets to the default gateway to be routed to the destination. (Real configuration are often more complicated; this explanation is strictly correct only with simple network configurations.)

For more details, see [default gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway) on Wikipedia.

In your example, the default gateway has address 10.0.2.2. Your computer will send data packets to 10.0.2.2 for routing whenever the destination is not directly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 10.0.2.2 via `eth0` is your default gateway.